# Integrate this function involving Greatest integer function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$ \int \sec^{-1}[-\sin^2x]dx = f(x) + c 
 $$

**$[y]$** denotes the **Greatest Integer Function**

Find the value of

$ f^{''}(\frac{8}{{\pi}x})_{_{x=2}}$

(Find the value of the second derivative of $ f(\frac{8}{{\pi}x})$ at x=2.)

I can't understand how should I start the question of this type. All I can think is that the Greatest Integer function will either be a 0 or a -1 but that's not helping also.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = \left[ -\sin^2 x \right]$.  We note that, unless $\sin^2 x$ is an integer, $g(x)$ is locally constant.  That means all of the derivatives of $g$ at $x$ will be zero (except where $\sin^2 x$ is an integer -- then all derivatives of $g$ will be undefined).

If we take a derivative of both sides of your original integral, we have

$$ f'(x) = \sec^{-1} [ -\sin^2 x] = \sec^{-1} \left( g(x) \right) $$

However, as noted earlier, since we are not considering any points where $\sin^2$ takes on an integer value, $g(x)$ is a flat function locally and equal to -1.  Thus, $f'(x)$ is flat locally and $f''(x) = 0$ at your point of interest.